# How can I delete "MiddleClick" app for Mac?

Tags: macos, mouse

I needed to use a middle click button for [AutoDesk Maya](http://www.autodesk.com/products/autodesk-maya/overview). So I downloaded and installed the [MiddleClick](http://clement.beffa.org/labs/projects/middleclick/) application.

However, I can't see any visible appearance such as a preference pane or an application icon in the Applications folder.

I tried to move it to the trash from my download folder, but it says I can't delete it because it's open.

How can I disable or delete this app?

Answer (score 4):

> So I downloaded and installed "MiddleClick" application.

If you're talking about this [MiddleClick.app](http://clement.beffa.org/labs/projects/middleclick/), you didn't really install it. It's just an application that runs whenever you double-click it and stops when you quit it from the menu bar. Nothing is installed.

First, quit the application if it's running. Its icon sits in the menubar.

[image]

Then, try to delete the *MiddleClick.app* file again.

If it still doesn't delete, or if you couldn't find the menubar icon, it might still have a process running. Open *Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app* and search for "MiddleClick":

[image]

Select it and click the big red *Quit Process* icon. Then, try to delete the file *MiddleClick.app* again.